# PHPMailer, no Email and no Error

Tags: php, email

I want to send a large mail from my webspace. This mail contains many variables, which are inputed through a form.

First I tried the php mail(), but I didn't receive any mail. I used mail() in another part of my website and from this script I receive a mail. So the function should work on my webspace.

For the large mail I tried to use PHPMailer, because the mail() didn't work as expected. The code for the PHPMailer is:

```
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'xxx.xxx.de'; 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;     
$mail->Port = 587;                          
$mail->Username = 'xxx';              
$mail->Password = 'xxx';                          
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                        
$mail->From = 'xxx@xxx.de';
$mail->FromName = 'xxx';
$mail->addAddress('xxx@xxx.de', 'xxx xxx');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                
$mail->isHTML(true);                                
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body    = $mess;
$mail->AltBody = $mess;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

After the script has finished, I don't get an error and I don't receive a mail. What could be a problem for this? How can I check, why my PHPMailer is not working? Has the require path to be absolute or relative?

Comment: Do you see the `Message has been sent` output? There are lots and lots of reasons you may not receive it, most of which have to do with it being blocked as spam. Graylisting is also a possibility, whereby it may eventually be delivered.

Comment: Check your junk folder! ;-)

Comment: Also check PHP error logs in case error reporting is turn off

Comment: If I understand correctly your sending a huge email? What if your code works just fine but the email is too big? have you tried with something smaller first?

Comment: You might want to also consider turning on the PHPMailer Debug: `$mail->SMTPDebug = 2`

Comment: I don't see the output from the script, therefore I think it doesn't send the mail.

Comment: Who is your web host? Some hosts block mails purporting to be from domains which aren't hosted there. I recently had an issue where I was trying to send mails via PHPMailer and was getting the error 'Mail function could not be instantiated' (or something like that). Just had to use a from address using a hosted domain and it worked.

Comment: @benJ Webspace and domain are from the same hoster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

//... another option code
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
//...another your code
dump($mail->send());

Each time ,you open this php-page,the mail result will let you know.what are you missed.

Comment: Okey the issue seems to be fixed. The mail comes trough, but it is in the spam folder.

Answer (score 0):

use try/catch as follow :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); // enable exceptions
try {
    $mail->isSMTP();
   //....
}
catch (phpmailerException $e) {
    echo $e->errorMessage();
}
```

Comment: I inserted this, but I don't get any output.

Comment: see my answer, I edited it refering to this : https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/943e0bd529e98a99a0658879b696018ad92e09c7/examples/exceptions.phps